# Set ImageView event in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been trying to show a random image on focus on a certain ImageView in Kotlin, unfortunately nothing happens. It looks logical to me and I can't find out what I'm doing wrong.

This is happening in fragment and this is my onCreateView function

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false)

    val array = intArrayOf(R.mipmap.ic_hello1, R.mipmap.ic_hello2)

    val image = rootView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView2)

    image.setOnFocusChangeListener(object: View.OnFocusChangeListener {
        override fun onFocusChange(view:View, hasFocus:Boolean) {
            if (hasFocus) image.setImageResource(array.random())
        }
    })
    
    return rootView
}
```

Comment: What does a focused imageview mean to you? I believe you'd be better off with an `onClickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the correct way to retrieve `Drawable` from `Array` resource.

**1. Create Resource:**

```
<resources>
    <integer-array name="images">
        <item>@drawable/image_1</item>              //Drawable reource
        <item>@drawable/image_2</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

**2. Retrieve `Drawable` by `TypedArray`:**

```
val images = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.images)

imageView.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(index, 0))    //index see below

images.recycle()        //may need
```

For your case, index should be: `(0..images.size - 1).random()`

Demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04y2J0MqYa0